# Can I upload service cloud component with Live Agent enabled to appexchange?

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud, managed-package

I am trying to upload a managed package to app exchange which contains a service cloud console component with live agent enabled and it gives me upload error "You can't export a console when you have Live Agent enabled." Any suggestions or workarounds for this ?